# sending entity properties from GET to Post

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc application using hibernate and jpa, I am having trouble getting an entity to travel from the `get` method to the `post` method, which is leading to other downstream problems.  Can someone show me how to set things up so that properties of the entity are still visible in the `post` method?

Here are the controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/providers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initUpdateProvidersForm(@PathVariable("encounterId") int encounterId, Model model) {
    Encounter encounter = this.clinicService.findEncounterById(encounterId);
    ArrayList<Provider> myproviders = new ArrayList<Provider>();
    myproviders.addAll(encounter.getProviders());
    System.out.println("............encounter id is:  "+encounter.getId());
    model.addAttribute("encounter", encounter);
    return "encounters/addProvidersForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/providers", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String processUpdateProvidersForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, @PathVariable("encounterId") int eid, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    Provider provider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(encounter.getProviderSelected());
    encounter.addProvider(provider);
    System.out.println(" :::::: encounter id is: "+encounter.getId());
    this.clinicService.saveEncounter(encounter);

    return "redirect:/encounters?encounterID={encounterId}";
}
```

**NOTE:** `encounter.getId()` prints out a number in `GET`, but prints out `null` in `POST`.  Why?  How can I fix this?

Here is the JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="petclinic" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<html lang="en">
<jsp:include page="../fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <jsp:include page="../fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
        <c:set var="method" value="post"/>
    <h2>Providers</h2>
        <div class="control-group" id="patient">
            <label class="control-label">Patient </label>
            <c:out value="${encounter.patient.firstName} ${encounter.patient.lastName}"/>
            ${encounter.dateTime}
        </div>
        <c:url value="/patientscodes.html" var="actUrl"/> 
${encounter.id} 
    <form:form modelAttribute="encounter" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="control-group">
            <form:select path="providerSelected" items="${providers}" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>
        </div>
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
        <td>
        </td>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">Add a Provider</button> <h3>    Link to delete will go here.</h3>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In View source for this <form:hidden path="id"/> .. Can you see the id No ? ..

Comment: @ArunM Yes, I can see the `id` number in view source.  Good question.  But using the `id` number to retrieve another copy of the entity from the database led to other problems with persistence further down the line.  Is there some way to simply pass this instance of the entity from `GET` to `POST`?

Comment: hmmm ... u could use @SessionAttribute ... That means the model will be stored in the session ... But it is just a workaround .. something else is causing your issue ..

Comment: @ArunM Thank you.  Where in my code above would I place at_SessionAttribute? And what additional code can I post to help you see what else is causing the issue?